# Insertion sort implementation

Tags: python, sorting

I am not sure why my insertion sort does not work. It is coded in python. When I try the test input I get [4].

```
  def insertion_sort(list):
        q =0
        temp = []  #list to hold sorted values
        size = len(list)
        while(q < size):
          if not temp: #if empty add first element of list
              temp.append(list[0])
          list = list[1:len(list)] #update list so it doesn't include first element
          for i in range(1,len(temp)):  #insertion step
              if(len(temp)==1):
                  if(list[0] > temp[0]): #if temp is size 1 insert element before/after
                      temp.append(list[0])
                  else:
                      temp.insert(0,list[0])

              else:
                  if(list[0] >= temp[i-1] and list[0] <= temp[i]): #insert value between two values
                      temp.insert(i,list1[0])
                  if(list[0] <= temp[0]):           # if less than min insert first
                      temp.insert(0,list1[0])
                  if(list[0] >= temp[len(temp)-1]): # if greater than max, insert last
                      temp.insert(len(temp),list[0])
          q=q+1
        return temp 

  list = [4,3,2,1] 
  print insertion_sort(list)
```

Comment: ...that's way the hell too complicated for an insertion sort. Simplify the logic...

Comment: Also, please do not use `list` as a variable name. It's a builtin already.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: temp is a sorted list and I simply take the the first value from list and insert it into the proper position in temp. During each iteration I remove the first value of list and insert it into temp. In the end I should have all my sorted values in temp.

Comment: oh what... you can do that so easily

Comment: Please do not ask questions of the form "this code doesn't work, can someone please help me?"  It's very hard to look at new code and spot errors in it.  If you want to ask for help, please describe what you've tried so far, where you think the problem might be, etc.  Commenting the code would also make it dramatically easier for us to help you out.

Comment: Also as a future reference, making one big function will just make your life more difficult. Instead, split your functions up into component parts. Like in this case; instead of just having a function named insertion_sort, make several functions like, look_for_smallest_number_in_temp and append_smallest_number_to_list

Comment: I edited my code with comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't implement this yourself. Use the `sorted()` builtin:

```
>>> mylist = [4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
>>> sorted(mylist)
[1,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: The OP probably needs to implement insertion sort for some reason (e.g. homework). But, this is the best general advice.

Comment: It would deserve a downvote if it was homework because he didn't explicitly tell us when posting the question

Comment: It's not for homework just out of curiousity

Comment: trying to improve my skills in algorithm design...looks like I am not very good

Comment: suffice to say its not easy and take practice

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to create a new insertion sort code or are you just interested in why it doesn't work?
Here is an insertion sort gived by [DaniWeb](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216689/sorting-algorithms-in-python):

```
def insertion_sort(list2):
for i in range(1, len(list2)):
    save = list2[i]
    j = i
    while j > 0 and list2[j - 1] > save:
        list2[j] = list2[j - 1]
        j -= 1
        list2[j] = save
return list2
```

Comment: I am still wondering why mine does not work